# How to fix form?

Tags: javascript

Help pls.
The form does not work when sending the data of the last name, first name and patronymic, constantly asks to enter 3 words

```
validFio: function () {
var fio = this.getData()["fio"];

if (!fio) {
  return "Не введен Ф.И.О.";
}

if (fio.split("/s+/g").length !== 3) {
  return "Ф.И.О. должно состоять из трех слов!";
}
return "OK";
```

},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
if (fio.split(" ").length !== 3) {
  return "Ф.И.О. должно состоять из трех слов!";
}
```

split accepts a separator